# Sum of numbers + 0

Tags: excel, sum, zero

I am having a problem with a small number. I am using `SUM` function to sum certain numbers. If I add a zero to the range, it is not displaying zero. I don't know why.

A1

```
=SUM(B1:R1)*-1
```

C1 to L1

```
266864  -100000 -15136.15   -23688.82   -120870 -7169   -5550   1224    -0.03   4326
```

A2

```
=SUM(B2:R2)*-1
```

C2 to M2

```
=SUM(C3:C3) =SUM(D3:D3) =SUM(E3:E3) =SUM(F3:F3) =SUM(G3:G3) =SUM(H3:H3) =SUM(I3:I3) =SUM(J3:J3) =SUM(K3:K3) =SUM(L3:L3) =SUM(M3:M3)
```

A3

```
=SUM(B3:R3)*-1
```

C3 to M3

```
266864  -100000 -15136.15   -23688.82   -120870 -7169   -5550   1224    -0.03   4326    0
```

A1 is displaying 0, but A2 and A3 displays 9.09E-13

Answer (score 1):

The number 9.09E-13 is another way (*scientific notation*) of saying 0.000000000000909495, a very small decimal number. What you are experiencing is a [15 digit precision floating point error](http://blogs.office.com/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/).

[image: Floating Point Error]

Typically, you would use the [ROUND function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ROUND-function-C018C5D8-40FB-4053-90B1-B3E7F61A213C) or something similar to remove the error (if you have to).

See [Floating-point arithmetic may give inaccurate results in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/78113) for more information.

Comment: May I know how this error comes. Just adding a zero how affects. However I will use round function. But it wont clear my entire problem because I use this for money transaction log.

Comment: The nature of the floating point error is too complex to explain in a comment and I've provided two links for more information. As you can see, the actual difference is very, very small and will not be displayed if you format the numbers as currency. It will only show up in straight comparisons like `if(9.09E-13=0, ...` which would be false. You can use rounding to correct this. There are other methods like *Precision as displayed* (which I generally do NOT recommend) that are detailed in the links I provided.

Answer (score 0):

as I think,
might be some different formula on A1 cell is already placed or the type of A1 Cell is **int** and Value becomes in decimal or else, so make try this formula in different cell.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you are using =SUM(C3:C3) etc.  That is, Why use the sum function on a single cell.  Unless there is a specific reason, I suggest you use = C3 instead.   I've found that using the summation on a single cell can sometimes return answers that are incorrect.  Don't know why, but it does.  Therefore, long ago I quit using the sum unless there is a range that includes more than one cell.